# Glueviz not labeling date-time correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

**Situation**

When I plot data using `glueviz`, a `datetime64` column is not being plotted correctly. Refer to x-axis in this figure:

[image]

Oddly enough, a few days ago, `glueviz` plotted date-time just fine. Refer to the x-axis in:

[image]

Between then and now, I did update all my packages using conda, but apart from that, no other changes I can recall.

Any ideas?

**Code**

Here is sample code:

```
from glue import qglue
import pandas as pd
from numpy import random

dataf = pd.DataFrame({})
dataf['date']=pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
dataf['value']=random.randint(0,10,72)

qglue(df=dataf)
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed (don't know in which version though) and it works as expected in the latest version- 0.13.3.

[image: screenshot]